# How to send form data in post request in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, url, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [POST in Objective-C iPad dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712861/post-in-objective-c-ipad-dev)

I'm very inexperienced with networking and the like, so please be kind.

I'm trying to send a post request with the following form data

`{"email":"JoeSmith@aol.com","password":"password","password_confirm":"password","name":"Joe Smith","cellphone":"4402415585","address":"Fake Street"}:`

So far here is what I have:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",SERVER_ADDRESS]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

My issue is I can't figure out how to include the form data in this request.  I'm sure there's a simple method of `NSMutableURLRequest` that can be used, but I haven't been able to figure out which one.

Comment: "I'm sure there's a simple method" - I wouldn't bet on it. Form data is a HTML-ism, the URL loading mechanism is intended to be generic across protocols, with some support for HTTP specifically. If you want to post form data, either [hit the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) and construct an appropriate HTTP request body, or look for a more comprehensive third-party HTTP client library.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420453/objective-c-post-request-not-sending-data?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert the JSON String to NSData Format. Then you would be able to set this data to HTTP Body in URLRequest object.

Adding code sample:

```
NSData* postData= [<yourJSON> dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request setHTTPBody:postData];

  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                delegate:self];

  [connection start];
```

Let me know in case of any more help...

Comment: can't able to convert josn into nsdata

Comment: @deepakkumar Use `SBJSON` library. It will solve all your json related problems.